# Dynamic BigQuery datasource in Google DataPrep - can it be done?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-dataprep

Can it really be right that I can't define a dynamic datasource using Dataprep. As far as i can see i can only point on a BigQuery Table. I need to point at a certain partion within a table. The naming of the partions always includes the date. like. "ga_20171113".

I really dont understand why i just cant define a SQL thoughwards BQ and use that as a source.

Answer (score 2):

Dataprep can ingest data from BigQuery views, which should hopefully be able to support your use case. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views has details on creating views. One note: Dataprep only supports views created using standard SQL rather than legacy SQL. So when creating a view from a query, please make sure that "Use Legacy SQL" is unchecked in the query options.

Comment: Created an account just to post this answer. You the real MVP